# Данные из БД в словарь Python

Tags: python, база-данных, flask

Работаю с базой данных и возник вопрос. При запросе в БД, результат образует обычный список и к значениям в ячейках приходится обращаться так : `product[0][15]`.
Как сделать, чтобы данные из БД записывались в словарь, в соответствии с названием ячейки в БД, например `product[0]['name']`
Вот пример того как на данный момент реализован запрос:

```
    def getTest(self):
    self.connections['DB_name'].execute(''' SELECT TOP (1000) [Oid]
                                                    ,[Code]
                                                    ,[Name]
                                                    ,[Article]
                                                FROM [DB_name].[dbo].[Products] ''')
    products = self.connections['DB_name'].fetchall()
    print(products)
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, нужно использовать какой-нибудь `ORM`, например `peewee` или `SQLAlchemy`.

Comment: А без них, только с pyodbc не получится?

Comment: Вот пишут можно через `Pandas`, он разберёт имена, ну либо вручную через `description`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704305/return-column-names-from-pyodbc-execute-statement

Comment: А вы через какой драйвер к базе обращаетесь ? Вот например pgmssql отлично словарь делает, если cursor передать параметр as_dict=True. см. пример в документации https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/

Comment: для pyodbc посложнее https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523148/5669174

Comment: @Mike спасибо, последний вариант сработал